# Visually Inspecting Data in R

Tags: r

First I want to point I am a very visual person, and so I would like to see the time series data I have in cells when I load it into R. I know I can use the Fix(data) command to vizually inspect the data in cells but what If have a single data vector.

How do I get R to show a single time series data vector in cells? Everytime I use the fix(singlevariable) it shows it akwardly as C(.....).

How do I show two or more data series in R in a cell visual format? I cant say fix(variable1, variable2)

Help! Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To view a single vector, you can use `View()`, which "invoke[s] a spreadsheet-style data viewer on a matrix-like R object."

```
X <- 1:10
View(X)
```

To view two equally long vectors side by side, just place them together in a data.frame and then view *that* with `View()`, `fix()` or `edit()`:

```
X <- 1:10
Y <- rnorm(10)
XY <- data.frame(X, Y)
fix(XY)   ## or View(XY) or edit(XY)
```

Comment: Hey Josh, Thank you so much!! Can I ask you another question, if I wanted to plot a chart and then plot a second without the first disappering, ie have two charts up, how do I that? Moreover, if I wanted to plot two series on the same chart could I use the simple plot command? Thank you!!

Comment: @alphabeta -- You can do all of that and much more. See, for example `?mfcol` or `?layout`, then `?lines`, or any of the many posts here on SO that demonstrate the **ggplot2** graphics package. You also might want to have a look at [some of the plots here](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/), all of which are accompanied by the code that makes them. Finally, if you think an answer here on SO answers your question, you can 'Accept' it by clicking the checkmark to its left. Oh, and also, welcome to SO!